# rbenv Ruby version 2.7.6 got ruby-build error and won't install

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to change temporarily to a specific Ruby version 2.7.6.

But encountered the following error.

```
$ rbenv install 2.7.6
Downloading ruby-2.7.6.tar.bz2...
-> https://cache.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/2.7/ruby-2.7.6.tar.bz2
Installing ruby-2.7.6...

BUILD FAILED (Ubuntu 22.04 using ruby-build 20220610)

Inspect or clean up the working tree at /tmp/ruby-build.20220831000029.32729.dL15Mz
Results logged to /tmp/ruby-build.20220831000029.32729.log

Last 10 log lines:
    from ./tool/rbinstall.rb:846:in `block (2 levels) in install_default_gem'
    from ./tool/rbinstall.rb:279:in `open_for_install'
    from ./tool/rbinstall.rb:845:in `block in install_default_gem'
    from ./tool/rbinstall.rb:835:in `each'
    from ./tool/rbinstall.rb:835:in `install_default_gem'
    from ./tool/rbinstall.rb:799:in `block in <main>'
    from ./tool/rbinstall.rb:950:in `block in <main>'
    from ./tool/rbinstall.rb:947:in `each'
    from ./tool/rbinstall.rb:947:in `<main>'
make: *** [uncommon.mk:373: do-install-all] Error 1
```

Comment: As the error message spells out, the log file `/tmp/ruby-build.20220831000029.32729.log` should contain further information. Please edit your question and add the last part of the contents from that log file. The error message contains the last 10 lines, but this isn't the complete message.

Comment: This was the error at the end of the log.
```/tmp/ruby-build.20220901003124.12612.mD5Jcv/ruby-2.7.6/lib/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:83:in `require': cannot load such file -- openssl (LoadError)```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ubuntu 22.04 comes with OpenSSL 3.0.2, but Ruby versions older than I think 3.0.4 still need the old OpenSSL 1.1.1x. The build process is looking for the header files of OpenSSL 1.1.1x, doesn't find them and tells you that: `cannot load such file -- openssl`.

The current version of the `rbenv` plugin `ruby-build` should take this situation into account and download the fitting version of OpenSSL, in addition to the Ruby sources:

```
Downloading openssl-1.1.1q.tar.gz...
-> https://dqw8nmjcqpjn7.cloudfront.net/d7939ce614029cdff0b6c20f0e2e5703158a489a72b2507b8bd51bf8c8fd10ca
Installing openssl-1.1.1q...
patching file test/v3ext.c
Installed openssl-1.1.1q to /home/henning/.rbenv/versions/2.7.6

Downloading ruby-2.7.6.tar.bz2...
-> https://cache.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/2.7/ruby-2.7.6.tar.bz2
Installing ruby-2.7.6...
```

You probably need to update your installation of `ruby-build` (and `rbenv` in general) to the most current version.

Comment: Thanks for this. Ruby version 2.7.6 has been released last April this year. Will update later if this resolved.

Answer (score 1):

This is resolved by installing/updating rbenv under Ubuntu.

Getting the new rbenv

```
curl -fsSL https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv-installer/raw/HEAD/bin/rbenv-installer | bash
```

Adding path

```
echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bashrc
echo 'eval "$(rbenv init -)"' >> ~/.bashrc
source ~/.bashrc
```